# HTML File can be copied but not opened?

Tags: permissions, samba, security, file-sharing

I am having a strange issue with an HTML file on a samba share being accessed via Win10 mapped drive. The file can be copied (Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V) to the windows server, but when I try to double click it directly while browsing to the share, it does not open. I thought this might be a read vs. execute permission issue, so changed permissions from `-rwxrw-r--` to `-rwxrwxr-x` - no effect.

- Samba Version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-81-generic x86_64)
- File is owned by the same user being used to connect to the samba share (`mw`)

Relevant smb.conf Config:

```
ntlm auth = true
allow insecure wide links = yes

[DataFolder]
   comment = Server Data Folder
   browseable = yes
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = no
   public = no
   read only = no
   create mask = 0750
   directory mask = 0750
   valid users = mw plex
   path = /data/
   follow symlinks = yes
   wide links = yes
   inherit permissions = yes
```

Can anyone please help with this? Happy to create/post log files if needed, please let me know which ones are helpful.

Comment: what happens if you select that file and choose your favorite browser with "open with" from the context menu? If it doesn't work, try to open it in the command line

Comment: Possible:  https://askubuntu.com/a/614118/231142 but only the part after EDIT:

Comment: @kanehekili - "open with" had same result - browser spins but nothing displays. Using `Get-Content` in PowerShell returns the contents of the file.
---
@Terrance - adding `acl allow execute always = True` to smb.conf had no effect

Comment: Can you open that html file with a texteditor?

Comment: @kanehekili - right click and `"Edit with Notepad++"` works, right click `"Open with... VSCode"` does not

Comment: Since samba runs on all of my Linux hardware without those problems, you should ask the seller of the OS you are doing this on - looks like you are trying to open it from a windows client